# BizTalk Error code: 0xC0002A21, An error occurred while attempting to access the SSO database

Tags: single-sign-on, biztalk

I have a BizTalk 2013r2 Standard Edition application server with a dedicated (Separate Sql Server) hosting the BizTalk databases.

Just lately, I've started to see a pair of errors in the event log. Typically these are raised about every couple of hour but there's no clear pattern - sometimes they can be as close a 15 minutes between two pairs.

The Error reads:

```
An error occurred while attempting to access the SSO database.


Function: LookupXp
 File: lookupserver.cpp:296
 Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding..
 SQL Error code: 0xFFFFFFFE
 Error code: 0xC0002A21, An error occurred while attempting to access the SSO database.
```

This is follows by a similar warning:

```
SSO AUDIT


Function: GetConfigInfo ({9AB60D40-9719-453D-89BD-3DAF212A7C17})
 Tracking ID: 2ad795a0-4d62-4545-a823-fd0ea492a833
 Client Computer: kochanski.xxx.local (BTSNTSvc64.exe:3152)
 Client User: xxx\biztalkhost
 Application Name: {DC9847A1-4D85-4C8A-B9D3-A58AFE352649}
 Error Code: 0xC0002A21, An error occurred while attempting to access the SSO database.
```

This is now a serious problem because on at least one occasion, this has prevented BizTalk from firing against the scheduled task adapter.

Anyone come across this error before?

Answer (score 0):

Has anything changed on a network level which might have caused a network glitch between your BizTalk server & your SQL server?

I've seen the same issue in the past after a SQL failover and restarting the WMI on the BizTalk-nodes solved it back then.

Comment: No network changes that I'm aware of. Tonight, I have rebooted production application and database servers. Unfortunately, I am still seeing the error in the event log.

Answer (score 0):

I already faced similare problem on sql server with always on when can't replicate data to the other node and that make the instance unvailable.Try also verify sql instance access from each Biztalk Node multiple times on the day

Comment: For this client - there's no always-on. In fact there's just a single dedicated Sql Server - no cluster.

Comment: I mean a cluster of the biztalk group.

Comment: It's running standard edition - a BizTalk group of 1 :)